# Can robots.txt be used to prevent bots from seeing lazily loaded content?

Tags: javascript, html, robots.txt, googlebot

Let's say that `googlebot` is scraping `https://example.com/page`.

- `example.com` has a `robots.txt` file that disallows `/endpoint-for-lazy-loaded-content`, but allows `/page`
- `/page` lazy loads content using `/endpoint-for-lazy-loaded-content` (via `fetch`)

Does `googlebot` see the lazy loaded content?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.